# GRASP Creator Pattern criteria

Tags: design-patterns

In a book (Applying UML and Patterns) that I am reading, below are some facts to decide if A object is a creator of another B object (GRASP Creator Pattern):

- B aggregates object A.
- B contains object A
- B records instance of A objects
- B closely uses A objects.

I am not clear difference of "aggregates", "contains", "records", and "closely used".

Can anyone explain the above criteria with some examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some examples given by Larman himself in the book:

- **Aggregates**:  Sale *aggregates* SalesLineItems
- **Contains**: the Monopoly Board *contains* Squares
- **Records**: the Register *records* Sales
- **Closely uses**: Sale *closely uses* Payments

You left out one criterion, and I'll give an example of it:

- **Has the initializing data for**: a use-case "handler" that's called from the system operation will often have parameters that are data needed for initializing an object. ProcessSaleHandler *has the initialization data* for SalesLineItem when the `enterItem(itemID : ItemID, quantity : integer)` system operation is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some ambiguity in these terms.

Most of them define real world relationships.
For example, we do not have any question when we talk to somebody and say "something contains something".

But in this case it would be nice to have some analogies which have formal definitions.

1) "aggregates". This is simple. This term corresponds to "Aggregation" relationship in UML

2) "contains". According to the book of the author we have the following example: "Monopoly Board contains Squares". In fact this relationship corresponds to "Composition".
Hence, we can conclude that this relatioship corresponds to "Composition" relationship in UML.

3) "records". This is the most "strange" relationshup. But again, let's look at his book. We can see that this relationship arises in the context of "Register" class. This is specific job for his Register and do nothing with something common. But we can generalize this and conclude that Register class uses "Association" between "Payment" and "Sale".
Therefore, we can conclude that "records" corresponds to "Association" in "UML".

4) "closely used". This is also simple. This term corresponds to "Dependency" in UML that marked with << use >>